# Neo4j Link prediction ML Pipeline

Tags: machine-learning, neo4j

I am working on a use case predict relation between nodes but of different type.
I have a graph something like this.

`(:customer)-[:has]->(:session) (:session)-[:contains]->(:order) (:order)-[:has]->(:product) (:order)-[:to]->(:relation)`

There are many customers who have placed orders. Some of the orders specify to whom the order was intended to (relation) i.e., mother/father etc. and some orders do not. For these orders my intention is to predict to whom the order was likely intended to.

I have prepared a Link Prediction ML pipeline on neo4j. The `gds.beta.pipeline.linkPrediction.predict.mutate` procedure has 2 ways of prediction: `Exhaustive search`, `Approximate search`. The first one predicts for all unconnected nodes and the second one applies KNN to predict. I do not want both; rather I want the model to predict the link only between 2 specific nodes 'order' node and 'relation' node. How do I specify this in the predict procedure?

Comment: what have you tried so far? what is the error and your expected result?

Comment: I have created a ML LP pipeline following the documentation in neo4js official website. I am not getting any error. I just want to predict links between only specific 2 nodes which I want not between all disconnected nodes. 

Basically the model should learn from all the positive relationships here in my case it is (:order)-[:to]->(:relation) and predict the probability of this link between the other disconnected order and relation node pairs.

Comment: This is probably a feature request that you need to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also frame this problem as node classification and get what you are looking for. Treat `Relation` as the target variable and it will become a multi class classification problem. Let's say that `Relation` is a categorical variable with a few types (Mother/Father/Sibling/Friend etc.) and the hypothesis is that based on the properties on the `Customer` and the `Order` nodes, we can predict which relation a certain order is intended to.

Some of the examples of the properties of `Customer` nodes are age, location, billing address etc., and the properties of the `Order` nodes are category, description, shipped address, billing address, location etc. Properties of `Session` nodes are probably not useful in predicting anything about the order or the relation that order is intended to.

For running any algorithm in Neo4j, we have to project a graph into memory. Some of the properties on Customer and Order nodes are strings and graph projection procs do not support projecting strings into memory. Hence, the strings have to be converted into numerical values.

For example, `Customer` age can be used as is but the order description has to be converted into a word/phrase embedding using some NLP methodology etc. Some creative feature engineering also helps - instead of encoding billing/shipping addresses, a simple flag to identify if they are the same or different makes it easier to differentiate if the customer is shipping the order to his/her own address or to somewhere else.

Since we are using `Relation` as a target variable, let's label encode the relation type and add that as a class label property on `Order` nodes where relationship to `Relation` node exists (labelled examples). For all other orders, add a class label property as 0 (or any other number other than the label encoded relation type)

Now, project a graph with Customer, Session and Order nodes along with the properties of interest into memory. Since we are not using `Session` nodes in our prediction task, we can collapse the path between `Customer` and `Order` nodes. One customer can connect to multiple orders via multiple session nodes and orders are unique. Collapse path procedure will not result in multiple relationships between a customer and an order node and hence, aggregation is not needed.

You can now use Node classification ML pipeline in Neo4j GDS library to generate embeddings and use embedding property on `Order` node as a feature vector and class label property as target and train a multi class classification model to predict the class that particular order belongs to or the likelihood that particular order is intended to some relation type.

Comment: Yes this makes a lot of sense. Thanks.. Will try it out

Answer (score 1):

This use case is not supported by the latest stable release of GDS (2.1.11, at the time of writing). In GDS pipelines, we assume a homogeneous graph, where the training algorithm will consider each node as the same type as any other node, and similarly for relationships.

However, we are currently building features to support heterogeneous use cases. In 2.2 we will add so-called context configuration, where you can direct your training algorithm to attempt to learn only a specific relationship type between specific source and target node labels, while still allowing the feature-producing node property steps to use the richer graph.

This will be effective relative to the node features you are using -- if you are using an embedding, you must know that these are still homogeneous and will not likely be able to tell the various different relationship types apart (except for GraphSAGE). Even if you do use them, you will only get the predictions for the relevant label-type-label triple which you specified for training. But I would recommend to think about what features to use and how to tune your models effectively.

You can already try out the 2.2 features by using our alpha releases -- find our latest alpha through [this download link](https://graphdatascience.ninja/neo4j-graph-data-science-2.2.0-alpha04.zip). [Preview documentation is available here](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/2.2-preview/machine-learning/linkprediction-pipelines/predict/#algorithms-link-prediction-pipelines-predict-examples-filtered). Note that this is preview software and that the API may change a lot until the final 2.2.0 released version.